# Replace duplicate values of incoming string

Tags: regex, typescript, angular-router

I have a problem with replacing some strings with duplicated values. Here is snippet:

```
const firstStep = this.router.url.replace(/[\d\/]/g, '.');
```

Above returns when url like `/project/1/cost-estimate` it gives me `.project...cost-estimate`. So i need to replace this `...` to `.` or `project.project` -> `project.`. How i do that ? Any advice ?

Comment: `this.router.url.replace(/[\d\/]+/g, '.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `+` to your regex to make the characters inside the bracket match one or more, effectively "squeezing" the result to one `.` character:

```js
console.log("/project/1/cost-estimate".replace(/[\d\/]+/g, '.'));
```